# How to start using any language at a backend using nginx?

Tags: nginx, web-applications, architecture

I see a lot of languages out there. I see some appealing to try out. Being a web developer, I'd like to play with some language in context of creating a web API backend.

So, assume, I'd like to create a webapp which is, for example, a number-crunching, or text-parsing, or data-mining service, whatever suitable for backend processing.

In the simplest case, I can have a set of small compiled apps in the language of choice, which have some standard in-out interface.

Is there a streamlined way to connect them to web with the help of nginx or apache? Or do I have to think about how to connect the app to web for each language? Do I need to make sure that these languages have some magic adapters or functionality to be used in web environment?

Say, I use 3 languages in my backend utility apps that can somehow be consumed. How do I connect them in a standard way as a set of web services?

Comment: Nginx (and any other web-server) doesn't care about language you backend is written. You should provide standard protocol to communicate. HTTP, fastcgi, uwsgi, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of standards, the [fastcgi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) protocol is one standard used to connect backend applications to something like a web server like nginx. This is pretty much how you allow an application to interface with your web server, by standard means.

However, you may want to recognize that your problem can be broken down into smaller chunks, and it is not always necessary for a back end application to interface directly with your web server.

For example, you could build your backend services separately from your web-facing application, and have the back end services communicate with each other, and with your web-facing application (which itself would interface directly with your web server), over some message bus.

Because not all back end services actually need to be exposed to the web directly. In fact, doing so is usually going to prove a poor architectural choice since you will more than likely have to conflate the HTTP interfaces that talk to the web with whatever internal protocols/interfaces your back end applications use.